# In how many ways can n couples (husband and wife) be arranged on a bench so no wife would sit next to her husband?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can n couples (husband and wife) be arranged on a bench so no wife would sit next to her husband?

I thought about this:

(Total amount of ways to sit 2n people in 2n sits)-(Using inclusion and exclusion to find that at least 1 wife sits next to her husband) And i get:

Let $A_1$ be the attribute where at least 1 wife sits with her husband, Then we "merge" up the husband and wife into a one person. We have $\binom n1$ ways to choose $1$ couple out of $n$ couples, And we are left with $2n-1$ to place $2n-1$ 'people' so we get $(2n-1)!$ and so on, And on a general note:

$(2n)!-(2\binom n1(2n-1)!-2^2\binom n2(2n-2)!+...2^k(-1)^k\binom nk(2n-k)!)$ And a bit simplified:

$(2n)!-(\sum_{k=1}^n2^k(-1)^k\binom nk(2n-k)!$)

Since i don't have answers to this question i wanna know if i did something wrong? Did i even look at the question right?

Comment: Definition of "near"? Do you mean "next to"?

Comment: $2n$ people can sit in $2n$ seats in $(2n)!$ ways, not $(2n)^{2n}$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, Yes. Edited.

Comment: @Arthur Aye, Thanks for noticing. Edited.

Comment: Don't you want to have factors like $2^k{n \choose k}$ in place of ${n \choose k}$ ? You can sit husband and wife next to each other in two ways...

Comment: @Feanor You are right. Didn't think about that. Thanks.

Comment: One minor thing: last sum is either from $k = 1$, or skip the term $2n!$ in front.

Comment: You actually can just do the sum from $0$ and omit the $(2n)!$

Comment: Doesn't $(2n-1)!$ include a permutation where a husband is next to his wife? I do understand that there are $(2n-1)$ ways to arrange the remaing people after choosing a couple $\binom n1$. I don't see why the $(2n-1)!$ won't include a couple who are adjacent.

Comment: You're right. If you want more problems with answers check __Counting: The art of enumerative combinatorics__ by G. Martin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arranging couples (husband and wife) on a bench so no wife would sit next to her husband?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033191/arranging-couples-husband-and-wife-on-a-bench-so-no-wife-would-sit-next-to-her)

Comment: @inavda The question you linked to is more recent. Wouldn't it make more sense to close in the other direction?

Comment: @ArnaudD. The other question has a more complete answer so I elected to close this one.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465318/showing-probability-no-husband-next-to-wife-converges-to-e-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am able to tell, the answer is correct.

After some unsuccessful attempts at simplifying the resulting expression, I went ahead and asked Wolfram for the answer. He came up with the formula:

$$ 4^n \frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}} \operatorname{Hypergeometric1F1}(-n,-2n,-2)$$

The weird looking term $\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}} $ is just $(2n-1)!!/2^n$, so this can also be written as:

$$ 2^n (2n-1)!! \cdot \operatorname{Hypergeometri1cF1}(-n,-2n,-2)$$

Unfortunately, it seems that $\operatorname{Hypergeometri1cF1}(-n,-2n,-2)$ is not anything nicer. Of course, I only have heuristic justification of the type "if it was something nicer, it wouldn't be called with such scary name, and Wolfram would be able to simplify it".