# Given $n$ pairs of brothers, in how many ways can we arrange them without 2 brothers sitting together?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having a weird time with this one. given $n$ pairs of brothers, I expect that if i sum all the possible ways to arrange $2n$ individuals in a row, then subtract the ways to sit $n$ brothers together I would get the amount of ways to sit them separate from each other. However I get: $$2n! - n!$$

Which seems to be the wrong answer. I found that for sitting 2 pairs, we get a total of $8$ combinations, so: $$4! - 2! = 24 - 2 = 22 \not = 8$$

I think the correct answer is sitting $n$ individuals who are not brothers with spaces, than sit the $n$ remaining in those spaces. We can do this in $n$ ways so all in all we get $$n!n! \cdot n$$
Why isn't the first solution working? Or is my second solution isn't really a solution also?

Comment: I don't understand the $n!$ term.  You need to exclude $\textit {any}$ two brothers from sitting next to eachother.  How is that given by $n!$  ?   Work it out explicily for, say, $n=3$ , compare your answer(s) to that.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391734/in-how-many-ways-can-n-couples-husband-and-wife-be-arranged-on-a-bench-so-no-w) is a duplicate.